# Testing Serial port application

Tags: c++, c, winapi, testing, serial-port

I have a code to send data to serial port. I just want to make sure that it is sending the data properly. I checked the function's return value and the number of bytes written and it is success.  Is there any other way to actually see the data whatever i am writing?

```
if(WriteFile(m_hSerialComm, pszBuf, dwSize, &dwNumberOfBytesWritten, NULL) != 0)
```

I tried to use "[Advanced Terminal Port software"](http://www.eltima.com/products/serial-port-terminal/)

but the data is not coming in that window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to test your software. If you have two serial ports then connect them with a cable and listen on the other port with a terminal application such as the one you mentioned. Otherwise, you could loop back on the same port by connecting pins 2 and 3 together. A hardware-free option would be to use virtual serial ports as provided by tools like [com0com](http://com0com.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: its helpfull, now  i am able to use Terminal application and send data and it works. Even with C# code it works but when i use CreateFile it fails saying cannot find Error file not found

Answer (score 0):

Assuming from your piece of code that you are developing on a Microsoft Windows operating system, I would recommend the [Portmon for Windows](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896644) "official" serial port monitoring utility. I have used it in in the past, and found it simple enough, and also quite useful specifically for its multiple filtering/search options (since sometimes the amount of data passed on your serial port is huge).

If all you want is a log of the data you have written to your own port, why not encapsulate your WriteFile (and maybe also your ReadFile) functions in some "utility" function(s) that reads/writes both on your serial port and in some log file? You could even add timestamps, and filter "whatever you are looking for" straight from your own code.

I found this last option really useful when remotely debugging applications with customers. You add a button in your application that toggles the logging on and off, then you simply have to ask your customer to hit the "log" button and to send you the results.

Comment: Note that PortMon is not supported on 64 bit versions of windows.